# Setting Non English Characters on OutputText from backing bean in ADF

Tags: java, oracle, unicode, oracle-adf

I have a requirement of displaying some non `english` (in my case `urdu`) characters on `af:outputtext` on some event. Here is my code

```
getOtMessage().setValue("گوشت مل گیا حے");
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(getOtMessage());
```

When i do this i get ??????????? marks instead. It's working fine when i set the characters on the `af:outputtext` from it's properties. but when i try to do the same from backing bean i am getting ?????? displayed instead.
Kindly help me here...

thanks

Comment: have you tried to set session parameters thru' oracle connection?

Comment: nope, what will it do to it ?

Comment: something like   " alter session set nls_lang='ARABIC_AMERICA.AL32UTF8' "

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, Java does not use `NLS_LANG` settings, see [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/global.htm#JJDBC28643)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, `NLS_LANG` can be set only on client (e.g. environment variable or Registry) but not by `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANG =...`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ok i saw it, thank you.

Comment: @UsmanRiaz  i think this page helps you :  http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/adf/develop-faces/GUID-A2D76C1E-363B-4755-9E87-370AB5CD790E.htm#ADFUI425

Answer (score 0):

Check which character set is used by your JSF (the first tag of your page).
You probably want it to be UTF - so should be something like:

Check which compile language setting you are using in the JDeveloper project properties.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to convert your message text in unicode and then use it in the code, try something like this

```
getOtMessage().setValue("\u06af\u0648\u0634\u062a \u0645\u0644 \u06af\u06cc\u0627 \u062d\u06d2");

AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(getOtMessage());
```

hope it works with you